# iPad WebView in Custom Cell - Disable webview scroll

Tags: iphone, ipad, webview

I have a custom cell which contains a webview. I don't want the webview to scroll, I want the table to scroll. So in essence I want to 'lock' the webview so scrolls get sent to the table instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the webview only for displaying the page and there is no need to interact with it, you can disable user interaction of webview so that it does not scroll.

```
UIWebView* webView;
// initialize the web view.

webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```